# Bubble chart with R

Tags: r, bubble-chart

I have a table with an abundance of species in different months. I want to make a bubble chart wherein the y-axis for abundance species and x-axis for the month while the radius of the bubbles for the abundance of species that I found in the month.

My data arrangement is like this

[image]

I want to end up the bubble chart with like this

[image: le]

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 1):

The following is a bubble graph created with a mock data set. I have tried to show how to plot a data set with a structure like the data set in the question and, as usual, this sort of problem is a data reformating problem. See [reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format). In this case I had to first have the row names as a new column. Only then the data was reformated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>%
  gather(key, Abundance, -id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(key, id)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Abundance), colour = "red", fill = "red", shape = 21) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 5)
df1[sample(prod(dim(df1)), 10)] <- sample(200:250, 10)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
dimnames(df1) <- list(letters[1:10], LETTERS[1:5])
```